# What is a good discussion forum for iOS developers

Tags: support, site-recommendation, forums

I assume that the below question would be inappropriate for Stack Overflow, as it is asking for well informed opinions, not specific answers. Am I right? Is there a good forum for this that anyone can recommend? Would this be appropriate any other Stack Exchange sites, like this one or Programmers?

> Is the iOS 6 auto layout too complex? I am just learning it, but at first look it seems far more complex than manually setting frames. I'd love to hear from experienced iOS developers who have embraced or rejected the new auto layout features for complex layouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a theoretical software engineering problem that will result in people posting well formed answers based on their experience, Programmers is a good place to turn. But keep in mind, 'discussion' by its nature is not something a Q&A site handles well. What remains is the degree of discussion permitted in order for a site to accomplish the goal of facilitating its topic.

The topic you use as an example, as written, is not a good fit anywhere on the network. The first part of it is basically a yes or no question, followed by the start to a very broad conversation. If it were more along the lines of asking what pitfalls someone might encounter should they embrace the auto layout features, while providing details of an existing implementation, it would be closer to an on topic question.

As far as 'discussion in general', you're probably better off finding a more traditional forum community for broader, open ended discussion. That really is the key, the questions you ask on Programmers *must* have some end in sight so they don't become a collection of opinions that aren't anchored in any real context or implementation.

If you're simply interested in discussing the pros and cons of something in general, a forum is your best bet. If you have an actual *implementation* for context and more *specific* concerns, your question can probably be asked in a way that would work on one of our sites. Questions must relate to an actual problem that you face in order to remain grounded.